# Actionscript 3 - Get size of ByteArray in bytes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, size, arrays

How can I get the size of a ByteArray in bytes?

I want to know, to see the difference in data transferred before and after the compression of a string (via ByteArray).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myByteArray.length` http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html

Comment: Hahahaha, why did I not see that.... I looked over that page several times, but somehow only looked at the Public Methods...
Thanks!

Comment: And I just figured out that I love the compress() method, it makes 4MB into 100kb :P Now that's a nice compression!